# Advanced Custom Fields - thumbnails

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Using [Advanced Custom Fields](http://advancedcustomfields.com) (ACF), I usually use the following code to display a specific field with a specific thumbnail size (using image ID):

```
$image = get_field('field_name_here'); 
$size = 'thumbnail_size_here'; 
if( $image ) { 
    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );
}
```

However, when I tried to use this code in a repeater field, it just spits out numbers.

I have tried updating the above code to:

```
$image = the_sub_field('field_name_here'); 
$size = 'thumbnail_size_here'; 
if( $image ) { 
    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );
}
```

However, this does not work, again it just spits out numbers. The full code would be like this:

```
<?php if(get_field('example_repeater_field')): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php while(has_sub_field('example_repeater_field')): ?>

        <li>
            <?php 
            $image = the_sub_field('field_name_here'); 
            $size = 'thumbnail_size_here'; 
            if( $image ) { 
                echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );
            } ?>
        </li>

       <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I have read the info on the ACF website but cannot see anything that related to custom thumbnail sizes.

Has anyone come across this before and found a solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "spits out numbers"? Can you show an example? The command is supposed to return a <img> HTML Tag not numbers.

Comment: What `thumbnail_size_here` is that? Did you create a thumbnail size with that name?

Comment: Do you have the image field set to return URL, ID, or Image Object?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a huge fan of `while` loops and multiples requests, so I usually prefer to get my data with only one request then loop through it with a `foreach`, like this :

```
<?php $fields = get_field('repeater_field'); ?>
<?php foreach ($fields as $field): ?>
    <?= $field['field_name']; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Also, you could try to have the image field set to return the image object (instead of the id), and to display the image like this : [(see the "Customized display (Object)" section)](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/)

```
<?php $image = get_field('image'); ?>
<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnailSize']; ?>
```

Which in your case would give us something like this (once you've set your acf field to return an object) :

```
<?php $fields = get_field('repeater_field'); ?>
<?php if( !empty($fields) ): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($fields as $field): ?>
            <li><?= $field['field_name']['sizes']['thumbnail_size']; ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got exactly this in a repeater field loop

```
<?php if(have_rows('column')):
while(have_rows('column')) : the_row(); ?>

    <?php   $image = get_sub_field('image');
    if( !empty($image) ):

    $url = $image['url'];
    $caption = $image['caption'];

    // thumbnail size (column) declared in functions.php
    $size = 'column';
    $thumb = $image['sizes'][ $size ]; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>


    <img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>">
```

But this only works if your return value is set as "image array" in ACF